# EasyAdmin 3 Can't diffuse decimal with numberfield

Tags: symfony5, easyadmin3

I'm working with symfony5 and easyadmin3.
There is no error displayed.
Here is the trouble :

I got a method get() in my entity

```
'''
    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $montageCharge;
////
  public function getMontageCharge(): ?int
    {
      var_dump((($this->montageCharge)/100));
        return (($this->montageCharge)/100);
    }
public function setWorkCharge(int $workCharge): self
    {
        $this->workCharge = $workCharge;

        return $this;
    }
'''
```

Which i'm using to get numbers with coma.
The dump confirm it with a number with coma and a float format :

```
Product.php:159:int 4
Product.php:159:float 0.7
```

However, i didnt manage to see it in my crud controller, where they only appear as a rounded number, no coma.
here is the configureField in my controller :

```
'''
NumberField::new('Work_Charge'),
'''
```

The crudcontroller is showing 1 instead of 0.7.
So my question is : how can i manage to diffuse correct number with coma, using easyadmin3 crudcontroller?

I tried a lot of other field so far, no one made it.

Comment: Try to use MoneyField instead of NuberField

Comment: Sure it work with moneyfield, but the currency's symbol is kind of annoying there :/ . And it doesnt work with 3 numbers post coma, wich i will encounter at some point on my current project...

Comment: You are returning `int` from get function, just change it to `public function getMontageCharge(): ?float` and it will return what you want.

Comment: It worked ! Nice, thank for your help ! The dump returning a float value prevented me to think about that ;). Have a nice day !